# req.body.variablename is undefined in express with body-parser middleware

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using express 4.14.1 version in my Nodejs application. I am also using body parser middleware for parsing form data but when I write console.log(req.body.variablename) I get undefined on the console.
my code is as follows

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //parses information from POST
const request = require('request');
const mongodb = require('../model/mongodb.js');
const smtpTransport = require('../model/mailer.js');
const Agent = require('../model/agentmodel.js');
const config = require('../config.js');
const intent = require('../intents.js');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file
router.get('/chat', function(req,res){
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/html/' + '/index.html'));
    res.render('pages/index', { heading: config.property.userheading});         
});

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file
router.get('/', function(req,res){
  // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/html/' + '/index.html'));
  res.render('pages/helpdesk');       
});

router.post('/createTicket', function(req,res){
  console.log("create ticket is called from email support");
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("and the details as follows ==>");
  console.log("username is ==> "+req.body.userName);
  console.log("message is ==>"+req.body.message);
  var json = {
          name :   req.body.userName,
          email :  req.body.userEmail,
          subject: 'Demo Subject',
          message:  req.body.message,
          topicId : req.body.topicId,
        };

        var options = {
          url: 'http://domainname/iprhelpdesk/upload/api/http.php/tickets.json',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-Key' : 'API-key'
      },  
      json:json
    };

   request(options, function(err, res, body) {
     if (res && (res.statusCode === 200 || res.statusCode === 201)) {
       console.log("response is ==>");
       console.log(res);
     }
     else {
      console.log("error is "+err+ " = and reponse code is ="+res.statusCode );
     }
    });
   res.render('pages/message');   
});
```

following is the output of the console

> create ticket is called from email support {
>   '{"topicId":{"Id":12,"name":"Basic IPR Query"},"message":"i want to
>   know about ipr","userName":"Pawan
>   Patil","country":"IN","userEmail":"pawanpatil.rocks@gmail.com","contact":"09665714555"}':
>   '' } and the details as follows ==> username is ==> undefined message
>   is ==>undefined POST /createTicket 200 21.161 ms - 104 error is null =
>   and reponse code is =400

and this is what chrome is sending as a form data

> {"topicId":{"Id":12,"name":"Basic IPR Query"},"message":"i want to
>   know about ipr","userName":"Jon
>   Snow","country":"IN","userEmail":"test@test.com","contact":"0123456789"}:

Request header is

> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

everything seems to be perfect but still, I am getting

> undefined

when I write console.log("username is ==> "+req.body.userName); in  my code.
please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem from changing

> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

header to the

> Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 1):

Move those:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Before this:

```
app.use(app.router)
```

So your bodyParser need to be initialized before the router. I also have read that using this:

```
app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
```

Insted of:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

May also fix the problem with undefined `req.body`

And one more thing to try is:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

Set `extended` to be false instead of `true`

Comment: after updating your suggestions into my code I am still getting undefined on console

Comment: try to also define your app to use router, before bodyParser `app.use(router)`

Comment: still undefined after adding app.use(router)

Comment: sry my bad, use dot `.` instead

Comment: One more thing to try. Remove app.use(app.router) completely since you didn't have it and change `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` to be `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));` and put back your `.json()` part

Comment: still undefined after changing extended: true to extended false and putting back .json() part